# Random number doesn't work and only displaying on the first element

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with my code. So basically when I click the first door, it's going to open an image. It shows an image depending on my condition random number, ex: 1 = door is empty, 2 = you find the person.

When I click the second door, the first door that just open, will return to the original image, the same thing if I open the third door, the second door will return to the original image

My problem is the door is only open on the first door, but the second and third don't open.
I think I need to add ".is-selected", but I'm not sure how to implement it.

But instead of using html, I want to use javascript.

```js
const doorTarget = document.querySelector(".door-track");
const doorClick = Array.from(doorTarget.children);

const door = true;

doorClick.forEach(function (test) {
  test.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (door) {
      const doorRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
      //const currentSelector = doorTarget.querySelector(".is-selected");
      //const image = currentSelector.nextElementSibling;

      //currentSelector.classList.remove('is-selected')
      //image.classList.add('is-selected')

      console.log(doorRandom);

      if (doorRandom === 1) {
        document.querySelector(".test1").src = "images/friends.png";
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".test1").src = "images/empty-room.png";

      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="door-wrapper">
    <div class=" door-track-container">
      <ul class="door-track">
        <li class="door-number">
          <a href="#"><img class="test1 is-selected" src="images/door.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="door-number">
          <a href="#"><img class="test1" src="images/door.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="door-number">
          <a href="#"><img class="test1" src="images/door.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Use `test.querySelector(".test1")` instead of `document.querySelector(..)` to target specific instances. Also chances of Math.random() returning `1` are very very very small

Comment: the test element is directing to the parent of ".test1"? I tried, but it doesn't make any different, the door still open only on the first element

const test = document.querySelector(".door-number");

if (doorRandom === 1) {
        test.querySelector(".test1").src = "images/friends.png";
      } else {
        test.querySelector(".test1").src = "images/empty-room.png";
      }

Comment: You have to create a `let` variable and assign `test` too it. read my answer you will understand.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the logic is relevant to the code at the question and the linked web page. Can you describe what the purpose of `if (doorRandom === 1) {} else{}` is at the question?

Comment: @guest271314 I have: const doorRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
I create condition for: if (doorRandom === 1), so when the random number hit #1, it displays the image(found friend), but when the random number hit anything else other than 1, it displays(empty door)

Comment: @Learner At which `<img>` element is the "empty door" displayed? Is that intended to be a random selection as well?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it's intended to be random selection as well. So to be clear, there are 3 images with "door close", when I click one of them and if it hits #1, it displays "found friend image", but if it hits #2 or #3, it displays "empty door". When I click the next door, the previous door is back to original image which is "door close"

Comment: @Learner That explanation should be included at the text of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

Add an `eventListener()` to the list (`<ol>`, `<ul>`, etc.) and then create if/else conditions in which the `<img>s` are the only elements to react to the event (ex. `click`, `mouseover`, etc). Pass the **Event Object** and use:

- [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will always return the origin of event (ex. clicked `<img>`, mouseover `<div>`, etc.)
- [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarge) is the element that has the `eventListener()`.

> ```
>  <ol id='list'>...</ol>
>  document.querySelector('#list').addEventListener('click', function(event) {...
> ```

Also if you use `<a>s` as buttons and you want them to stop jumping, change the following:

> ```
>   <a href="#/"></a>
> ```

Just add a forward slash: `/`

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo.**

```js
// This will be event.currentTarget
const doorTarget = document.querySelector(".door-track");
// Collect all img.test1 into a NodeList
const doors = document.querySelectorAll('.test1');

// Remember to always pass the event object
doorTarget.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Set all img.src to default
  doors.forEach(function(door) {
    door.src = "https://placeimg.com/160/90/nature";
  });

  // if the clicked element is NOT the list itself... 
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    // if the clicked element's class is .test1
    if (event.target.className === "test1") {
      // Get random number in the range of 1 to 3
      const doorRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
      // if that number is 1...
      if (doorRandom === 1) {
        // Change the clicked src to a person image
        event.target.src = "https://placeimg.com/160/90/people";
      } else {
        // Otherwise change clicked src to a tech image
        event.target.src = "https://placeimg.com/160/90/tech";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="door-wrapper">
  <div class=" door-track-container">
    <ul class="door-track">
      <li class="door-number">
        <a href="#/"><img class="test1" src="https://placeimg.com/160/90/nature"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="door-number">
        <a href="#/"><img class="test1" src="https://placeimg.com/160/90/nature"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="door-number">
        <a href="#/"><img class="test1" src="https://placeimg.com/160/90/nature"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i wrote it as you like, make sure to read the comment

```js
const doorTarget = document.querySelector(".door-track");
const doorClick = Array.from(doorTarget.children);

const door = true;


doorClick.forEach(function (test) {
  let t= test;
  test.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // reset all selected classes, remove this if not needed im not sure you want it
  doorClick.forEach((item)=>   item.querySelector("img").classList.remove("is-selected")) 
  
    if (door) {
      const doorRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
      
     var img = t.querySelector("img");
      
      console.log(doorRandom);
      // add class selected to the image
      img.classList.add("is-selected")
      // change the src or what ever to the image
       if (doorRandom === 1) {
        img.src = "images/friends.png";
      } else {
        img.src = "images/empty-room.png";

      }
      
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.is-selected{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="door-wrapper">
    <div class=" door-track-container">
      <ul class="door-track">
        <li class="door-number">
          <a href="#"><img class="test1" src="images/door.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="door-number">
          <a href="#"><img class="test1" src="images/door.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="door-number">
          <a href="#"><img class="test1" src="images/door.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really close answer, the problem when I click different door, the door that I open doesn't close, is there a way when I click different door, the previous door close automatically?

Also, I didn't know that we need to create loops since I already have loop on the first spot.

Comment: look at the comment `reset all selected classes` there you will be able to reset all previous images. right now i only remove `is-selected` from all previous images. but you could reset/close or change all previous images to the default value.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
document.querySelector(".test1").classList.add("is-selected");
```

to add a class and

```
document.querySelector(".test1").classList.remove("is-selected");
```

to remove the class again

Edit: to get all elements use querySelectorAll() and loop through the HTML Collection

Comment: Will only affect first element of that class found in the page

Comment: I tried with querySelectorAll(), but it doesn't let me open any door